# Which terms is corresponding for Map, Filter, Foldable, Bind etc from Category Theory?

Tags: math, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, category-theory

I became interested and did not find in one place a list of corresponding terms:

`Map <-> Morphism`

`Foldable <-> Catamorphism`

...

Who can supplement the list of terms

Comment: `bind` is composition in the Kleisli category.

Comment: I have the feeling that parts of this have been asked in serveral questions already... but: monads in CT are usually defind by a natural transformations η (for `return`) and µ (for `join`, instead of `>>=`), which are sometimes called _unit_ and _multiplication_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is on the right track but there are so many more ways in which Category Theory connects to other concepts. I also find that relating Category Theory to Type Theory brings more to the table than relating Category Theory to transformations. I say relating, because while Math and Computer Science may use the same terminology, they are not the same; one is not interchangeable with the other.

### [Physics, Topology, Logic and Computation: A Rosetta Stone](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.0340v3.pdf)

by John C. Baez and Mike Stay

Category Theory: object X
Computation: data type X

Category Theory: morphism f: X → Y
Computation:  program f: X → Y

Category Theory: tensor product of objects: X ⊗ Y
Computation: product of data types: X ⊗ Y

Category Theory: tensor product of morphisms:  f ⊗ g
Computation: programs executing in parallel:  f ⊗ g

Category Theory: internal hom: X ⊸ Y
Computation: function type: X ⊸ Y

### [relation between type theory and category theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relation+between+type+theory+and+category+theory)

from nLab

Category Theory: counit for hom-tensor adjunction
Type Theory: beta reduction

Category Theory: unit for hom-tensor adjunction
Type Theory: eta conversion

### Yoneda embedding

> The Yoneda embedding is familiar in category theory. The continuation passing transform is familiar in computer programming. 
>   [They’re the same thing!](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/01/the_continuation_passing_trans.html) Why doesn’t anyone ever say so?

by Mike Stay

### Other references

There is so much more to this question than can possibly be put into an SO answer.

When I was looking into this in the past I asked most of my questions at [StackExchange: Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) and updated the most useful references as part of the [Category Theory tag](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/category-theory/info). Most of what you seek is found in those references.

### TL;DR

If I could have created tables with the SO Markdown I would have added a lot more, but without being in a table seeing them in a list just loses its impact.

If you find Category Theory of interest, then you should also look at [HoTT](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) (Homotopy Type Theory)

Comment: Thanks, Your answer is useful for me

Comment: Of interest: [Reference request: Category theory as it applies to type systems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/64001/268)

Comment: Of interest: [Is Category Theory useful for learning functional programming?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/3256/268)

Comment: Of interest: [What do functions look like, if I stated out with the categoical model of my type theory?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19089/268)

Comment: Of interest: [Solid applications of category theory in TCS?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/944/8739)

Comment: Of interest: [Calculating monad transformers with category theory](https://oleksandrmanzyuk.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/calc-mts-with-cat-th1.pdf)

Comment: Of interest: [Notions of computation and monads](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Moggi91.pdf)

Comment: Of interest: [Learning road map for functional programming from the viewpoint of category theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19871/8739)